# I want to calculate the mean of an image using centre weighted average metering technique in opencv

Tags: opencv, visual-studio-2012

I want to calculate the mean of an image. But the overall mean is not necessary. As the images  has information in the centre, I am interested in ROI only in the centre. So can anyone help me to just consider the centre part using centre weighted average metering technique to get it.. please.. in opencv...

Comment: well, first, let's try to cheat, and calculate the avg,mean of a roi: `Scalar m = mean( img( Rect( cx-cw/2, cy-ch/2, cw/2, ch/2) ) );`

Comment: can u please tell it clearly

Comment: please can anyone answer this. I need it for my project.